# Highlight cells in hovered row in HTML table which have no rowspan

Tags: css, html-table, hover

I've got an interesting problem here:

There is a table with a handful of cells, some of them have rowspans:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|    |    | c4 | cx |
|    | c2 +----+----+
|    |    | c5 | cx |
| c1 +----+----+----+
|    |    | c6 | cx |
|    | c3 +----+----+
|    |    | c7 | cx |
+----+----+---------+
```

With the following CSS I want to have only the cells c4, c5, c6, c7 and the corresponding cx cells highlighted when the row is hovered:

```css
tr:hover td:not([rowspan]) {
    background: #F1F1F1;
}
```

Works like a charm when c4 .. c7 are hovered - only the cell itself and its corresponding cx cells get the new background color.

When c1 to c3 are hovered, the row c4 is also hovered - makes perfect sense with the selector in mind. The problem is that i do not want it to behave this way and do not know how to stop it.

Any ideas? If requested, I'll provide a fiddle.

Comment: When hovering `c2` which cells should be highlighted? And for `c1`?

Comment: In both cases, no cells should be highlighted

Comment: Always provide the markup.  It's a pain to write all that out by hand.

Comment: @cimmanon you're right, i would've delivered the markup with the fiddle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't create a single selector that does that, but you can add another selector that overrides highlighted background:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  tr:hover td:not([rowspan]) {background: red}
  tr:hover td[rowspan]:hover ~ td {background: none;}
</style>
<table>
  <tr><td rowspan=2>c1</td><td>cx</td><td>cx</td></tr>
  <tr><td>cx</td><td>cx</td></tr>
</table>
```

`td:hover ~ td` means any `<td>` (with the same parent) that is after the hovered `<td>`.

Comment: I just used your first row of CSS with the :not and it worked fine, so +1.  However, I'm working in Chrome.  The :not selector is not supported by IE8 and earlier per [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp).

Comment: @Airn5475 what you're saying is correct, but in general please avoid w3schools - they're [not affiliated with W3C and have low quality material](http://w3fools.com). Use [W3C-endorsed WebPlatform.org](http://docs.webplatform.org) or [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/).

Answer (score 2):

One approach, I'd suggest:

```
$('td').not('[rowspan]')
.hover(function () {
    $(this)
    .siblings()
    .andSelf()
    .not('[rowspan]').addClass('highlight');
}, function(){
    $(this)
    .parent()
    .find('.highlight')
    .removeClass('highlight');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Vfyew/1/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).
- [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: thank you for the snippet. unfortunately i forgot to mention that i searched for a CSS only solution. anyway, +1

Comment: @Joshua: sorry, I should've *seen* that there was no jQuery, or even JavaScript tag. I was convinced that one was there, though, for some reason.